# What encryption types are illegal in the U.S.A

Tags: encryption

I live in the USA. I am a developer, interested in creating an application with encryption. I am interested in learning what the illegal/restricted encryption types are.

Clarify:

What are the encryptions that are not accessible to a regular programmer that is not working for a company.

Comment: What makes you think there is any encryption that is illegal in the US? Let's start there.

Comment: AFAIK, NSA Suite A is classified, so it's not accessible. But the first amendment of the USA constitution mandates that written knowledge cannot be made illegal, so anyone can implement NSA Suite B or any other non-classified crypto algorithm.

Comment: Anything patented is "restricted", but that is probably not what you mean? Please [edit] to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @mikeazo well, the US *certainly has* **illegal numbers.** I claim this is a technical ban on encryption, up to your choice of Godel numbering. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Effectively none.  Some ciphers are patented so you won't find them in OpenSSL.

In 1995 Bill Clinton signed an [Executive Order 13026](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13026) that transferred control of encryption from the department in charge of munitions export to the commerce department.  [Since then](http://www.nytimes.com/2000/01/13/business/us-removes-more-limits-on-encryption.html) there has been a period of liberalization where now the only true restrictions are on exporting to countries under embargo.

You are free to write software that uses any key length to protect the messages.